# Prove by induction a property of a tree graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Prove by induction (and without the use of cycle definition) that if to delete a leaf vertex from a tree graph it will stay as a tree graph.

I think Ive got it wrong but what I did is the following:
By the inductive defenition of a tree graph of 'n' vertices, its a graph that been constructed out of a tree of 'n-1' vertices and an attached leaf.
But, the same goes for a tree with 'n-1'.

So, can I tell that this is why if we eliminate 1 vertice of a tree graph it will still be a tree graph?

Comment: You should describe in more detail what your "inductive definition of a tree graph" is, and what kinds of trees you have in mind. – You are asked to prove that you can delete *any* leaf, and not just the last one, and are left with a graph having a recursive history.